# Downcasting an implementation using an interface template

Tags: c++, interface, downcast, pimpl-idiom, raw-pointer

I'm implementing a generic interface that can bridge different implementations of some base class.

The interface utility is written as follows:

```
// InterfaceUtils.h
//

// Base object class
class IBaseObject {
    virtual ~IBaseObject() = default;
};

// Unknown object adapter
class UnknownObject
{
public:
    UnknownObject() = default;
    UnknownObject(const UnknownObject& from);
    UnknownObject(UnknownObject&& from) noexcept;
    explicit UnknownObject(const IBaseObject& from);
    explicit UnknownObject(IBaseObject* from)
    {
         SetPointer(from);
    }
    virtual ~UnknownObject()
    {
         DeletePointer();
    }

    template<class Interface>
    const Interface* RetrieveInterface() const
    {
        if (!m_pObject)
            return nullptr;
        return dynamic_cast<const Interface*>(m_pObject);
    }
    template<class Interface>
    Interface* RetrieveInterface()
    {
         if (!m_pObject)
             return nullptr;
         return dynamic_cast<Interface*>(m_pObject);
    }
    UnknownObject& operator=(const UnknownObject& other);
    UnknownObject& operator=(UnknownObject&& other) noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] bool IsNull() const
    {
        return m_pObject == nullptr;
    }
    void SetNull();
protected:
    [[nodiscard]] virtual const IBaseObject* GetPointer() const
    {
        return m_pObject;
    }
    virtual IBaseObject* GetPointer()
    {
        return m_pObject;
    }
    void SetPointer(ISymplektBaseObject* pObject)
    {
        m_pObject = pObject;
    }
    void DeletePointer() const
    {
        // Q: Unsafe for memory leaks ?
        // delete m_pObject;
    }
private:

    //>! stored pointer to object
    IBaseObject* m_pObject = nullptr;
};

// Generic object interface template
template <class Interface>
class ObjectInterface : public UnknownObject
{
public:
    explicit ObjectInterface(const IBaseObject& other)
        : UnknownObject(other) { }
    explicit ObjectInterface(IBaseObject* other)
        : UnknownObject(other) { }
    explicit ObjectInterface(const UnknownObject& other)
        : UnknownObject(other.RetrieveInterface<Interface>() != nullptr ? other : UnknownObject()) {  }
    explicit ObjectInterface(UnknownObject&& other) noexcept
        : UnknownObject(other.RetrieveInterface<Interface>() != nullptr ? std::move(other) : UnknownObject()) {  }
   ObjectInterface(const ObjectInterface<Interface>& other)
        : UnknownObject(other) { }
   ObjectInterface(ObjectInterface<Interface>&& other) noexcept
        : UnknownObject(std::move(other)) { }
   ~ObjectInterface() override
    {
          UnknownObject::~UnknownObject();
    }
    ObjectInterface& operator=(const ObjectInterface<Interface>& other)
    {
          return UnknownObject::operator=(other);
    }
    Interface* operator->()
    {
          return GetInterface();
    }
    const Interface* operator->() const
    {
          return GetInterface();
    }
    Interface* GetInterface()
    {
          return RetrieveInterface<Interface>();
    }
    const Interface* GetInterface() const
    {
          return RetrieveInterface<Interface>();
    }
};
```

If it's any use, I'll also write the contents of the *.cpp:

```
// InterfaceUtils.cpp
//
#include "InterfaceUtils.h"

void UnknownObject::DeleteInterface(UnknownObject& obj)
{
    if (obj.IsNull())
        return;

    obj.SetNull();
}

UnknownObject::UnknownObject(const UnknownObject& from)
{       
    if (auto* fromObj = from.GetPointer(); fromObj != nullptr)
    {
        SetPointer(const_cast<IBaseObject*>(fromObj));
        return;
    }

    SetPointer(nullptr);
}

UnknownObject::UnknownObject(UnknownObject&& from) noexcept
{
    SetPointer(from.GetPointer());
    from.SetPointer(nullptr);
}

UnknownObject::UnknownObject(const IBaseObject& from)
{
    auto* pObject = &from;
    SetPointer(const_cast<IBaseObject*>(pObject));
}

UnknownObject& UnknownObject::operator=(const UnknownObject& other)
{
    if (this == &other)
        return *this;       
    
    if (auto* fromObj = other.GetPointer(); fromObj != nullptr)
        SetPointer(const_cast<IBaseObject*>(fromObj));
    else
        SetPointer(nullptr);
    
    return *this;
}

UnknownObject& UnknownObject::operator=(UnknownObject&& other) noexcept
{
    DeletePointer();

    SetPointer(other.GetPointer());
    other.SetPointer(nullptr);
    return *this;
}

void UnknownObject::SetNull()
{
    DeletePointer();
    m_pObject = nullptr;
}
```

The purpose of classes `IBaseObject`, `UnknownObject` and `ObjectInterface<>` is to be able to extend `IBaseObject` to different implementations, for example:

```
class ITestClass : public IBaseObject
{
public:
    ITestClass() : IBaseObject() {}
    ITestClass(const double& val)
       : IBaseObject(), m_Value(val) { }

    void SetValue(const double& val)
    {
        m_Value = val;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] double GetValue() const
    {
        return m_Value;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] virtual double ProcessValue() const = 0;

protected:
    double m_Value = 0.0;
};

//
// test class implementation returning m_Value^2 with ProcessValue
//
class TestClassSquareImpl : public ITestClass
{
public:
    ~TestClassSquareImpl() override
    {}

    TestClassSquareImpl(const double& val)
        : ITestClass(val) {}

    [[nodiscard]] double ProcessValue() const override
    {
        return m_Value * m_Value;
    }
};

//
// test class implementation returning sqrt(m_Value) with ProcessValue
//
class TestClassSqrtImpl : public ITestClass
{
public:
    ~TestClassSqrtImpl() override
    {}

    TestClassSqrtImpl(const double& val)
        : ITestClass(val)
    {
    }

    [[nodiscard]] double ProcessValue() const override
    {
        return sqrt(m_Value);
    }
};
```

Used as follows:

```
const double dataValue = 3.0;
const auto testObjSqr = TestClassSquareImpl(dataValue);
const auto testObjSqrt = TestClassSqrtImpl(dataValue);

const auto iTestObjSqr = ObjectInterface<ITestClass>(testObjSqr);
const auto iTestObjSqrt = ObjectInterface<ITestClass>(testObjSqrt);

std::cout << iTestObjSqr->ProcessValue() << "\n";    // out: 9.0
std::cout << iTestObjSqrt->ProcessValue() << "\n";   //  out: 1.73205080...
```

**The question is**: From my previous experience method `UnknownObject::DeletePointer` should delete raw `m_pObject` to avoid memory leaks, but when it does, an exception is thrown because a memory block of a derived instance is about to be freed. Is it safe to just leave the `m_pObject` pointer undeleted? Does it get deleted anyway after `UnknownObject` is destroyed?

inb4: I've already tried using `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` resulting in inability to access methods from derived implementations (e.g. `TestClassSquareImpl::ProcessValue` or `ITestClass::GetValue`).

Edit: The exception thrown by `free` is: `Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 0000016F756B0000, 00000004B0AFF988 )`. I first encountered it when running an example in gtest, but the same thing happens whenever the program goes out of scope, resulting in `DeletePointer` call.

Comment: Those copy-constructors/assignments are the most likely culprit. The fact you have to use a `const_cast` should be a dead giveaway that the approach is wrong.

Comment: Can't you use `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: as I mentioned, I had no luck with using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` because the downcasting lost my ability to access derived data (e.g.: `iTestObjSqr->Value()` throws an access violation exception).

The `const_cast` is a naughty hack, I know. I was forced to use it when combining `SetPointer` with the copy constructor or copy-assignment operator.

Comment: @Martin Those operations result in the same pointer being assigned multiple times, meaning you end up calling `delete` multiple times on the same object. You need to tackle copies completely differently, presumably via some kind of `clone()` virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

I took @Frank 's advice to remove the `const_cast`'s and implement a `Clone` method, with abstract declaration:

```
[[nodiscard]] virtual IBaseObject* Clone() const = 0;
```

in `IBaseObject` which must be implemented in derived classes:

```
[[nodiscard]] IBaseObject* Clone() const override
{
    return (new TestClassSquareImpl(*this));
}
```

and analogously in `TestClassSqrtImpl`. The `Clone` method was required in copy construction and copy-assignment (whenever a different interface with its own instance, or a different instance itself are accessed and copied, e.g.: `SetPointer(fromObj->Clone());`)

also, there was repeated deletion caused by

```
~ObjectInterface() override
{
    UnknownObject::~UnknownObject();
}
```

invoking its base destructor.

With these adjustments, the `delete m_pObject` doesn't throw.

It should be noted, that putting `std::shared_ptr<IBaseObject> m_pObject;` limits the scope of accessing any members to `IBaseObject` members. Correct me if I'm wrong, but in this case, `m_Value` would need to be defined as a field in `IBaseObject`

Your insights are really appreciated.

**EDIT**: I found out I was reinventing the wheel. Specialized [STL casts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) can easily perform the downcasting in the test example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cmath>

class Base
{
public:
    Base(const double value)
        : m_Value(value) {}

    double& GetValue()
    {
        return m_Value;
    }

    void SetValue(const double value)
    {
        m_Value = value;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] virtual double ProcessValue() const = 0;
protected:
    double m_Value{ 0.0 };
};

class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedA(const double value)
        : Base(value) {}

    [[nodiscard]] double ProcessValue() const override
    {
        return m_Value * m_Value + m_SpecializedValueForA;
    }

private:
    double m_SpecializedValueForA = 1.0;
};

class DerivedB : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedB(const double value)
        : Base(value) {}

    [[nodiscard]] double ProcessValue() const override
    {
        return sqrt(m_Value) + m_SpecializedValueForB;
    }

private:
    double m_SpecializedValueForB = -1.0;
};

enum class [[nodiscard]] ImplementationType
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1
};

class BaseWithSwitchableImplementation
{
public:

    BaseWithSwitchableImplementation(const double value, const ImplementationType type)
    {
        InternalSetAndInitImplementationWithValue(type, value);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] double ProcessValue() const
    {
        return m_Impl->ProcessValue();
    }

    void SetAndInitImplementationWithValue(const ImplementationType type, const double value)
    {
        if (type == m_ImplType)
            return; // nothing happens

        InternalSetAndInitImplementationWithValue(type, value);
    }

private:
    void InternalSetAndInitImplementationWithValue(const ImplementationType type, const double value)
    {
        m_ImplType = type;
        m_Impl = nullptr;
        if (type == ImplementationType::A)
        {
            const auto implAPtr = std::make_shared<DerivedA>(DerivedA(value));
            m_Impl = std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(implAPtr);
        }
        else if (type == ImplementationType::B)
        {
            const auto implBPtr = std::make_shared<DerivedB>(DerivedB(value));
            m_Impl = std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(implBPtr);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR: Invalid ImplementationType!\n";
        }
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Base> m_Impl;
    ImplementationType m_ImplType;
};

int main()
{
    const double value = 3.0;
    const auto instanceA = std::make_shared<DerivedA>(DerivedA(value));
    const auto instanceB = std::make_shared<DerivedB>(DerivedB(value));

    const auto basePtrA = std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(instanceA);
    const auto basePtrB = std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(instanceB);

    std::cout << "basePtrA->ProcessValue() = " << basePtrA->ProcessValue() << "\n";
    std::cout << "basePtrB->ProcessValue() = " << basePtrB->ProcessValue() << "\n";

    const auto switchableImplA = BaseWithSwitchableImplementation(value, ImplementationType::A);
    const auto switchableImplB = BaseWithSwitchableImplementation(value, ImplementationType::B);

    std::cout << "switchableImplA.ProcessValue() = " << switchableImplA.ProcessValue() << "\n";
    std::cout << "switchableImplA.ProcessValue() = " << switchableImplB.ProcessValue() << "\n";

    auto switchableImplAToB = BaseWithSwitchableImplementation(value, ImplementationType::A);

    std::cout << "switchableImplAToB.ProcessValue() = " << switchableImplAToB.ProcessValue() << "\n";

    switchableImplAToB.SetAndInitImplementationWithValue(ImplementationType::B, value);

    std::cout << "switchableImplAToB.ProcessValue() = " << switchableImplAToB.ProcessValue() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
basePtrA->ProcessValue() = 10
basePtrB->ProcessValue() = 0.732051
switchableImplA.ProcessValue() = 10
switchableImplA.ProcessValue() = 0.732051
switchableImplAToB.ProcessValue() = 10
switchableImplAToB.ProcessValue() = 0.732051
```

Which is exactly what I needed.